# How to detect focus out on div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on accessibility, so I am testing my app using TAB key. I would like to do something when following div element loses focus.

So in my imagination this onBlur function should only fire when I would click TAB key on button 2 and move to button 3. But this onBlur is call on every TAB click in inside this div. Why this is happening?

What should I do to fire function only when I will be outside of this div. So after click TAB key on button 2 and move to button 3, this function should be fired

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div onBlur={() => console.log('Blur')} style={{ padding: '20px', border: '1px solid #000'}} tabIndex={0}>
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
      </div>
      <button>3</button>
      </>
  );
}
```

Comment: If this is React/JSX, please add the relevant tag (Probably `reactjs`) Or use a non-React snippet to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply take advantage of the [`e.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) that is available in the `onBlur` callback to detect if:

1. The related target is the current target `<div>` itself, or
2. The related target is a descendant of the current target `<div>` by using the [`Node.contains` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

If neither conditions are met, then you conditionally invoke the necessary logic:

```
<div
  onBlur={(e) => {
    if (
      e.relatedTarget !== e.currentTarget &&
      !e.currentTarget.contains(e.relatedTarget)
    ) {
      console.log("Blur");
    }
  }}
  tabIndex={0}
>
  {/* Content here */}
</div>
```

I have made a proof-of-concept Codesandbox to demonstrate the code above, but I've swapped out the `<button>` with `<input>` just for a more visual test:

[image: Edit happy-roman-bpjpuq]

Comment: arguably `e.relatedTarget !== e.currentTarget` will always be true without specific application of a tabindex on the div

Answer (score -1):

If you only want onBlur to fire when leaving button 2 you can just move the onBlur to button 2

```
return (
<>
  <div style={{ padding: '20px', border: '1px solid #000' }} tabIndex={0}>
    <button>1</button>
    <button onBlur={() => console.log('Blur')}>2</button>
  </div>
  <button>3</button>
</>
```

);

Comment: Not if the OP is specifically looking for focus moving out of the container because they could be moving backwards to button 1.